# How to use nf-config for locating netcdf library

Tags: netcdf, linux-mint

There is a script where I need to enter the netcdf library location. But instead the script file states

```
# Where is the NetCDF library root located? Hopefully nf-config can tell us
# but you might need an appropriate "module load netcdf***" beforehand
NETCDF_HOME=$(nf-config --prefix)
```

I have tried searching for how to use module load netcdf and nf-config but cannot find any help. I am using linux mint and gfortran.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `nf-config` script that is normally installed with netcdf-fortran. Install netcdf (C) and netcdf-fortran with whatever package manager you use, e.g.,

```
brew install netcdf netcdf-fortran
conda install libnetcdf netcdf-fortran
sudo port install netcdf netcdf-fortran
sudo dnf install netcdf netcdf-devel netcdf-fortran netcdf-fortran-devel
sudo aptitude install netcdf-bin
```

Once you have `nf-config` on your path, the script you pasted above should work fine.